# angular 4 Component Inheritence

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 4. I am creating an application having almost 50 components with all the components having almost same constructor definition i.e same set of services injected in every constructor. So I created a class with all services dependency injected and then extended all components to use that class. But that is not working. it's giving me error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: router_1 is not defined
    at eval (abstract.component.ts:11)
    at eval (abstract.component.ts:21)**

```
import { TerminalService } from './../services/generic/terminal.service';
import { SessionService } from '../services/generic/session.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/generic/config.service';
import { UtilityService } from '../services/generic/utility.service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export abstract class AbstractComponent {
  constructor(
    protected router: Router,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    protected configService: ConfigService,
    protected utilService: UtilityService,
    protected acRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected sessionService: SessionService,
    protected terminalService: TerminalService,
    @Inject('CONSTANTS') protected constantsRef: any
  ) { }

}

export class AbstractLogisticsComponent  extends AbstractComponent{
  retryLimit: any;
  subscription: Subscription;
  overlayStatus: boolean;
  OverlayComponent: any;
  countryCode: string;
  txt: string;
  myContent: any;

  constructor(
    protected router: Router,
    protected logisticService: LogisticService,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    protected configService: ConfigService,
    protected utilService: UtilityService,
    protected acRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected sessionService: SessionService,
    protected terminalService: TerminalService,
    @Inject('CONSTANTS') protected constantsRef: any,
    @Inject('LOGISTIC_CONSTANT') protected LOGISTIC_CONSTANT: any,
  ) {
    super(router, translate, configService, utilService, acRoute, sessionService, terminalService, constantsRef);
  }
```

Comment: super();
this.router  = touter;

Comment: but this gives me compilation error.. as Parent class constructor definition is not synchronous with call ..

Comment: 50 components with the same services injected... something is really wrong here. Another point is that you need to post a plunkr reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by moving constructor away from AbstractComponent.
Instead I have

```
abstract class FilterComponent {
  public abstract route: ActivatedRoute;
  public abstract router: Router;
}
class RadioFilterComponent_ extends FilterComponent {
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router) { super(); }
}
```